# Curious badge: what is it?

Tags: support

Just out of curiosity: I was recently awarded with the [***Curious***](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/185/curious) badge, which is described as:

```
Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintained a positive question record.
```

Maybe my English is lacking, but this is not clear to me. I am sure I did not asked new questions in 5 different days. And the last few questions I posted have no up votes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just means you've posted 5 questions on 5 separate days which have a positive score.

It's a new badge that has been applied retro-actively, which is why you've been awarded it now. It's not because of something you've done recently.